# What is the meaning of "heutig" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, german-to-english

A recent Slow German Podcast contains the following sentence:

> Das Mittelalter dauerte im heutigen Deutschland von ungefähr 800 bis ungefähr 1500.

I do not understand the use of the word *heutig* in a sentence talking about a period over 500 years earlier.

Comment: Btw, there is a hint in the podcast itself. "Zunächst einmal war Deutschland kein eigenes Land, sondern es war unterteilt in viel Fürstentüme"

Comment: It would be much better to say "Das Mittelalter dauerte *im Gebiet* des heutigen Deutschland von ungefähr 800 bis ungefähr 1500." Meaning that the circumstances characterizing the Middle Ages persisted here longer than, say, in Florence. The distinction is also important because e.g. the republic of Florence *was* nominally part of the Holy Roman Empire which came as close to Germany in the Middle Ages as you get.

Comment: I'm tempted to answer "das Mittelalter dauerte im heutigen Deutschland schonmal gar nicht."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a bit wonky, admittedly.

It means to say "in the area that makes up today's Germany" - There was no "Germany" in the middle ages - The area consisted of numerous kingdoms and empires.

The author trying to be precise here messes up the meaning quite a bit:
Obviously, there's no longer any middle age in today's Germany either (except in some very remote areas...).

Comment: It's particularly wonky because it would be hard to argue that the "middle ages" represents a different time span in different parts of Europe (unlike, say, the Renaissance). Actually, my first reading was "In Germany today, the term 'middle ages' is used to refer to the period from 800 to 1500". But I think your reading is the intended one.

Answer (score 20):

It refers to the territory of today's Germany. As one united state in more or less modern form, Germany didn't exist until late 19th century (1871). Hence we must resort to using this word when referring to what was on this territory during the Middle Ages or in the Stone Age.
Further example:

> Die römischen Gebiete im heutigen Deutschland verteilten sich auf die Provinzen Germania superior, Germania inferior und Raetia.

Comment: Ich halte diese Formulierung für falsch, da sie zu anachronistischen Aussagen führt. Im heutigen Deutschland gibt es keine römischen Gebiete mehr, genauso wenig wie wir uns im heutigen Deutschland im Mittelalter befinden oder vor kurzem noch befunden hätten. Bei diesen Beispielen kann man noch erahnen, was wohl tatsächlich gemeint ist, aber das muss nicht so sein.

Comment: Was will man da schon machen, man verwendet die Sprache so. Dass es etwas mehrdeutig ist, ist an sich selbst kein Problem, so kennen viele Sprachen keinen Unterschied zwischen Arm und Hand, oder müssen/sollen/dürfen/können/brauchen , was man auch als schrecklichst falsch einstufen könnte aus der konservativeren präskriptivistischen Perspektive. Noch ein Beispiel: gekürzte Aussprachen wie "ich dreh" müssen nach der Logik auch nicht so sein, denn man könnte das dann mit "ich Dreh" verwechseln (als DaF-Lernende*r auf jeden Fall), usw.

Comment: (1) *„Was will man da schon machen[?]“* – Genauer Sprechen. Und dabei bedarf es oft nur kleiner Änderungen: „Das Mittelalter dauerte auf dem Gebiet des heutigen Deutschlands ...“ (2) *„Dass es etwas mehrdeutig ist, ist an sich selbst kein Problem [...]“* – Großes Kontra. Solche Ungenauigkeiten sind die Hauptursache vieler Missverständnisse. Ich weiß, dass Sie wissen, dass es im heutigen Deutschland keine römischen Gebiete mehr gibt, obgleich Sie wortwörtlich genau das geschrieben haben. Doch oft weiß man es eben nicht, wenn der Verfasser etwas anderes gemeint als geschrieben hat.

Comment: Übrigens gibt es den sehr verbreiteten umgekehrten Nonsense: "In der ehemaligen DDR..." - es gibt keine nicht-ehemalige DDR. Genauso könnte man vom "ehemaligen Römischen Reich" sprechen.

Comment: Diese Formulierung kann keinesfalls zu 'anachronistischen' Aussagen führen. Da muss man schon absichtlich Missverständnisse konstruieren, was man aber immer kann. Gerade die Verwendung von 'heutig' macht ja klar, was gemeint ist.

Comment: @Nick, gerade das überflüssige Wort "ehemalig" sorgt dafür, dass die Aussage geographisch verstanden wird. Auch in anderen Sprachen finden Wörter wie "ehemallig" solche Verwendung, vgl. "in the ex-USSR", rus. "в бывшем СССР". Dabei kann ich gut nachvollziehen, dass solche Ungenauigkeiten der natürlichen Sprachen jemanden jucken können. So gibt es im Russischen keine eindeutige Antwort auf die Fragen mit Verneinung wie "kommst du nicht?" im Gegensatz zum Englischen oder Deutschen; man wird da ständig missverstanden.

Comment: I can only support @BjörnFriedrich: "Die römischen Gebiete im heutigen Deutschland!?" Wait, what?

Comment: @Dan Da stimme ich dir nicht zu - "ehemalige DDR" ist und bleibt unsinnig und ist keineswegs immer geografisch gemeint.
Und die Antwort auf verneinte Fragen ist im Deutschen ebenso schwierig.

Comment: @Nick, 1) aus puristischer/präskriptivistischer Sicht - vielleicht. Aber so spricht man nun mal. Auch auf English und Russisch 2) Doch es gibt "doch".

Answer (score 4):

In English you could say: "in what is now Germany".

Comment: You are right, but this information is already provided in tofro’s answer (“in the area that makes up today's Germany”) and – in other words – also in the answer with the most upvotes by Dan. Also, it is very short, and one-sentence answers are generally frowned upon.

Comment: Despite Philipp's misgivings, I upvoted the answer. It provides something that other answers don't have, namely an English translation. Of course it doesn't provide a different cause for the confusion, and it also doesn't go into a deep analysis - both are not needed. It is a useful addition to the other answers, and as such, to me it is upvote worthy.

Answer (score 1):

Despite what is stated in the original podcast, and repeated in the various answers, it is not correct to say that there “was no Germany in the Middle Ages”, and certainly not that “Germany didn't exist until late 19th century (1871)”.  The Latin “Germania” is used since the time of the Roman Empire, and the German “Deutschland” is (as Pfeifer puts it):

> aus Fügungen wie mhd. in Diutischemi lande (Annolied, um 1085)
>   entstanden, im Mhd. vereinzelt schon in Diutisk lant (Kaiserchronik,
>   um 1150), spätmhd. Tiutschland; Zusammenschreibung setzt sich
>   endgültig erst im 16. Jh. durch.

Source: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Deutschland

Of course, the boundaries of “Germania” and “Diutisk lant” are not the same as those of the modern country, but they do imply the existence of a specific geographic and ethnic entity. In this sense, “im heutigen Deutschland” means the territory corresponding to modern “Germany”, but not necessarily identical with what mediaeval people called “Diutisk lant” or “Germania”

Comment: Einen Staat, der den Begriff "Deutschland" in seinem Namen trägt, gibt es erst seit 1949. Zwischen 1945 und 1949 war das Gebiet des heutigen Deutschland von den alliierten Mächten besetzt. Da gab es keinen Staat, der "Deutschland", "deutsches Reich" oder ähnlich hieß. Vor 1945 gab es ein "Großdeutsches Reich" ein "Deutsches Reich" ein "Deutsches Kaiserreich", ein "Heiliges römisches Reich deutscher Nation" usw. Vor dem 15. Jahrhundert war dieses Gebiet nur als  "Heiliges römisches Reich" (ohne weitere Zusätze) bekannt. ...

Comment: ... Insbesondere war ein paar Jahrhunderte lang auch Österreich ein Teil des  "Heiligen römischen Reichs deutscher Nation", daher kann dieses Reich nicht als 100%iger Vorgänger des heutigen Deutschland gelten. Das Heilige römische Reich hatte vielmehr Ähnlichkeit mit der EU. Es war ein Bündnis vieler Kleinstaaaten (Herzogtümer, Fürstentümer, Bistümer usw.) die alle mehr oder weniger souverän waren.

Comment: Ich kann @HubertSchölnast nur beipflichten: Bei Historikern wird der Begriff verwendet, der zu der Zeit politisch gültig war. Denn der Name indiziert damit den Zeitraum, von dem gesprochen wird. D.h. auch, dass "Deutschland seit 1949" ein wenig ungenau ist, besser ist BRD und DDR - auch wenn in DDR kein 'Deutschland' enthalten ist ;-) Falls im Alltag mit "Deutschland" mal der Zeitpunkt genommen wird, als die Römer im Teutoburger Wald geschlagen wurden ... stelle ich sehr ironische Gegenfragen zu "Deutschland".

Comment: @HubertSchölnast. Wer hat von einem "Staat" gesprochen? Ich nicht.

Comment: @fdb: Ist denn Deutschland kein Staat? Der Gegenstand der Frage ist das "heutige Deutschland", und ich wüsste nicht, wie ich das anders als als Staat interpretieren sollte.

Answer (score -6):

I take it to mean that it is accepted in Germany today, that the Middle Ages were between the given dates.

Comment: Erm, no. It isn't

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. please consider answer the question "what is heutige". And providing some sources is useful for any claim.

Comment: Your reading of the sentence is highly obscure. Since it is *possible* to read it as such (but it’s definitely not intended by the author), I vote to not delete the answer.